# PgAdmin III - Number of lines returned during insertion

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-9.4

Not crucial question here, just curiosity.

I am inserting data via multiple scripts in a base running in PostgreSQL.

I wanted to test the time requested to end the insert, so I requested many times the number of lines in the table as follow :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "table";
```

I noticed that **everytime** the number of line is following a schema : last digits (hundreds, tens and units) are the same as the firsts (millions and thousands).

By example :

- if there was around 39k lines, the number of lines returned was `39039`,
- if there was around 8518k lines, the number of lines returned was `8526518` <sub>(8518000 + 8518)</sub>

#### Any idea from where it come? Is it by default? or maybe a personal config?

---

<sub>More info :</sub>

- Same behaviour on psql.
- I am adding 1k inserts by connection to the base, so I don't think it's related.
- When the inserts are over, the correct number of lines is returned.
- I did enought requests to ensure that's not coincidence.
- I am working on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I am adding 1k inserts by connection to the base, so I don't think it's related.*

I think it is related. You are probably adding **exactly** 1001 rows in each batch.

All these numbers are multiples of 1001.

Comment: Ahah just under my nose... gj. (in 23h, you got the reward)